# Why link only answer flag was disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, link-only-answers

It is said that link only answers can be flagged as not an answer, so when I did that for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977704/login-page-for-multi-page-javascript-application/17977796#17977796) answer, Why my flag was marked as disputed?

The answer only contains a link, what if the link breaks in the near future, then the answer will be useless? or is it because of higher rep users are allowed to post link only answers?

Comment: That's not link only answer. It's link with explanation which sums up to a fair answer. Maybe not excellent and don't deserve upvotes, but shouldn't be deleted in my opinion. If you'll delete all answers with external links, you'll end up deleting millions of answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: what if the link is broken, will it have the meaning?

Comment: Like I said, we can't delete all answers with external link and not always it's possible or recommended to copy the external link contents to the post. This one is a fair answer with link to site that isn't likely to go down in the near or far future. (not before Stack Overflow at least)

Comment: "link to site that isn't likely to go down in the near or far future" , only because its a microsoft link??

Comment: Yes, with all the lack of love I'm pretty sure they won't shut down. Link to some private site/blog is a different story with more chances to die at some point.

Comment: Remove the link, and what is left is “The good news are that you don't need to build the login system, Microsoft did it for you: let me introduce Membership System: Just expose this api to your end users. And it's a bad idea to have a single credential for everybody, you better assign credentials to each user.” There's useful information left. A link-only answer is one where if you remove the link, all that's left is “see here” or other non-informative content.

Answer (score 5):

The poster

1. named an ASP.net feature that might solve the OP's problem
2. provided the link to the documentation of that feature
3. provided advice on what OP should/should not do.

So no, the answer you referenced/flagged is not a link-only answer

It *would have* been a link-only answer if the *entire* answer is simply a link (i.e. only contains #2), like

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx

In addition to the fact that it is not a link-only answer, like what the [shady wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191351/why-link-only-answer-flag-was-disputed#comment595191_191351) said, the linked site is a reliable site due to the fact that it is the official documentation site of a fairly popular framework.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is about api which we can only give link to download those api files.

And there is some sort of explanations about why and how to use that api in the answer, so the answer is a good one , so your flag got disputed.

You can see [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5644908/756941) [link-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17960403/756941) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939919/756941) in Stack overflow which are seen useful.